# Controlling spacing in custom ggplot2 geoms

Tags: r, coding-style, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am creating a custom ggplot geom to represent Edward Tufte's 2nd boxplot 
[image: Tufte #1 can lead to misinterpretations of data, but #2 is nice]

An eventual goal is to be able to use this as an axis to show marginal distributions succinctly.
I am basing my work on [Jeffrey Arnold](http://www.jrnold.me/about.html)'s [ggthemes](https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes).

I have gotten a output that looks right, but making it work in a general case has led to the question at hand.
[image: tufte box plots in ggplot2]

Below is the code that is used to draw the middle lines (i.e. the lines that replace the box):

```
median.thickness <- 0.25
box.offset <- 0.01
boxdata <- data.frame(
    x = data$x + box.offset,
    xend = data$x + box.offset,
    y = c(data$upper, data$lower),
    yend = c(data$middle + median.thickness, data$middle - median.thickness),
    alpha = NA,
    common)
```

Clearly the values `median.thickness` and `box.offset` will need to be different depending range of the plot, so it would be ideal to compute them based on those values. Is there a way to accomplish this in a geom?

Comment: it's probably best done in the stat function that already returns upper, lower, middle

Comment: Aren't the stats are computed for each geom? That could lead to spacing being different for each box plot drawn on the same axes.

Comment: How do you want these elements to relate to plot size? (could be problematic, at least for `median`thickness`, if some groups have very tightly distributed central 50%). Alternatively, maybe set it to span a third (for example) of the shortest box being plotted on those axes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've come up with a good solution.

```
boxdata <- data.frame(
    x = data$x,
    xend = data$x,
    y = c(data$upper, data$lower),
    yend = c(data$middle, data$middle),
    alpha = NA,
    common)
  box_grob <- GeomSegment$draw(boxdata, ...)
  offset <- 0.004
  box_grob$x0 <- box_grob$x0 + unit(offset * common$size, "npc")
  box_grob$x1 <- box_grob$x1 + unit(offset * common$size, "npc")
  box_grob$y1 <- box_grob$y1 + unit(c(1.5 * offset, -1.5 * offset), "npc")
```

This code produces the same plot as posted in the question and scales appropriately with line thickness.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly not what you asked for, but here's an example of how you might achieve this with base graphics.

```
tufte <- function(x, groups, data, offset=0.15, lwd=2, 
                  xlab=NULL, ylab=NULL) {
  if(is.null(xlab)) xlab <- deparse(substitute(groups))
  if(is.null(ylab)) ylab <- deparse(substitute(x))
  b <- boxplot(eval(substitute(x~groups)), data, plot=FALSE)
  nm <- b$names
  stats <- b$stats
  plot.new()
  plot.window(ylim=range(pretty(range(stats))), xlim=c(0.5, ncol(stats)+0.5))
  mdn.span <- 0.15*min(stats[4, ] - stats[2, ])
  invisible({
    segments(rep(seq_len(ncol(stats)), each=2), c(stats[c(1, 4), ]),
             y1=c(stats[c(2, 5), ]), lwd=lwd, lend=1)
    segments(seq_len(ncol(stats)) + offest, c(stats[2, ]),
             y1=c(stats[4, ]), lwd=lwd, lend=1)
  })
  segments(seq_len(ncol(stats)) + offset, stats[3, ] - mdn.span, 
           y1=stats[3, ] + mdn.span, col='white', lwd=3, lend=1)
  axis(1, at=seq_len(ncol(stats)), labels=nm)
  axis(2, las=1)
  title(xlab=xlab, ylab=ylab)
  box(lwd=2)
}

tufte(weight, feed, chickwts)
```

Here, the x-offset is set to a constant, which to me makes sense since with more groups, the range of the x-axis will be larger and you'll want smaller offsets accordingly (I imagine?). The height of the gap denoting the median is defined as a fifth of the interquartile range of the group with the smallest IQR. This means, however, that if a group with a very small IQR exists, the plotting of all groups will be affected.

[image: tufte]